If I change some heading texts, how to reflect these changes in the texts of the existing hyperlinks (to these headings)
I'm using the solution given in this answer to make a link from "Link to Rule 1" to the chapter "Rule 1" (which is a heading of level 1).

But I realize that if I change the text "Rule 1" of the heading, the text of the link is not changed, even if I refresh the field codes by selecting all and pressing F9.

Is there a way to reflect automatically the changed heading text in the link(s)?
Additionally, if it's possible, my original document contains existing links and many heading texts have been changed, is it possible to automatically fix all the links automatically?
Thank you.
NB: if I create a table of contents and I change the text of a heading, by pressing F9 on the table of contents, the changed headings are automatically updated. So, I hope there's a solution for the links too.
NB: I'm using Word 365, but I guess the issue exists in other versions, answers for other versions are welcome too.

You could use a Table of Contents without page numbers.
You could use a cross-reference field.
Both of those, when updated, will change to reflect to update the text. Neither, though, will have the formatting of a hyperlink even though they will act as such unless you choose to not have them act that way when you form them.

Thanks, it works (menu References > Captions > Cross-reference). I need them as link, so I have kept "Insert as hyperlink" checked, and for the formatting I have created a non-paragraph (character) style, blue + underlined, and I assigned it to these fields.
